# AngularJS REST resource - refresh query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asynchronous, angularjs-resource

How can I refresh query result of $resource in AngularJS without refreshing the page?

My page:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in items">
    <p>{{tile.name}}</p>
  </div>

  <button ng-click='??'> Reload tiles </button>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
(function(angular) {
    var AppController = function($scope, Item) {
        Item.query(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response ? response : [];
        });
    };

    AppController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Item'];
    angular.module("myApp.controllers").controller("AppController", AppController);
}(angular));
```

I know it's possibly very noob question however I could not find any solution yet (today is my first day with AngularJS, so any help is appreciated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller, create a function that is responsible for loading the data:

```
var AppController = function($scope, Item) {
    $scope.refresh = function(){
         Item.query(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response ? response : [];
        });
    };

    $scope.refresh();
};
```

In your button, just call the function:

```
<button ng-click='refresh()'> Reload tiles </button>
```